# How does $R[Y\times_K X]\simeq RY\otimes_{RK} RX$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory, tensor-products

Suppose a group $G$ acts on two finite sets $X$ and $Y$ by a left action on $X$, and a right action on $Y$. If $R$ is a commutative, unital ring, and $K$ a subgroup of $G$, and $R[Y\times_K X]$ is the permutation module of the amalgamated product $Y\times_K X$, why does
$$
R[Y\times_K X]\simeq RY\otimes_{RK} RX?
$$

This isomorphism is used a bit when composing parabolic induction functors, but I am curious why it is true. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Show that there is a map $RY \otimes RX \to R[Y\times_K X]$ such that $$RY\otimes RK\otimes RX \rightrightarrows RY \otimes RX \to R[Y\times_K X]$$ is a coequalizer diagram. Since $$RY\otimes RK\otimes RX \rightrightarrows RY \otimes RX \to RY \otimes_{RK} RX$$ is also a coequalizer diagram (by definition), and since coequalizers are unique up to isomorphisms, the result follows.

Comment: Thanks, I'll think about this. Are the non-indexed tensor products just over $R$?

Comment: Yes, they are over $R$.